# Suggestions on moving the existing users to a new table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a Users Table (id,name)
 and another table User_detail(id,user_id,additional_details)
where additional_details is a hash

i have added the user_detail table just now as an extension of my application.
 the logic i have used is ,

Once the user signs up -- a default entry will be made in the User detail table with empty values.. (done by having  a after_create: set_defaultvalues)
 And then inside the app , the user can edit their additional_detail..

But the already existing users are missing in the user detail .

What could be done for them .Please give suggestions..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just:

```
script/console production

User.all.each{|u| u.set_defaultvalues if u.user_detail.blank?}
```

Comment: is it possible to write a rake task for this one so that to make each user to run it in their local ?? if so how ??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `user_detail` to each user, then why don't you just add new column to users table? Then you don't need another model, another association and you don't have to think about creating child object for every user. You will also save some joins in your queries.

Comment: already i am having many columns in Users table thats why i thought of keeping it in a separate table..

Comment: @Aruna: you keep things in another table if you want some kind "to-many" relation, or if data from that new table is not always associated with the other model, or if this data from new table is very rarely queried in comparision with data from first table. In any other cases, no matter how many columns you have in first table, you should add new column instead of new table. This way everything is much simpler.

Comment: @Aruna: yes and you want to have this field for each user, and probably you want to load this field quite often. That is why I'm saying that it should be new column added to users table.